# Undefined index when clicking next page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

Im doing function of search data and the result was in paginate . The paginate working for the first search but when i clicking next page or last page it return error like below

> Undefined index: cu

Here is my code

pagination2.blade.php

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-right text-center-xs">
        <ul class="pagination pagination-sm m-t-none m-b-none">
            @php
                if(isset($_GET["q"])){
                    $pg_url_param = url()->full() . "&page=";
                }else{
                    $pg_url_param = url()->current() . "?page=";
                }

                $pg_current = $paginationRecord->current_page;
                $pg_last = $paginationRecord->last_page;
            @endphp

        @if ($pg_current <= 1)
            <li><a type="button" class="first changePg disabled" name="first" id="firstPg" value="&nbsp;&Iota;&nbsp;&lt;&nbsp;" title="Click here to show first page records">&laquo;</a></li>
            <li><a type="button" class="previous changePg disabled" name="prev" id="previousPg" value="&nbsp;&lt;&lt;&nbsp;" title="Click here to show previous page records">&lsaquo;</a></li>
        @else
            <li><a href="{{ $pg_url_param }}1" type="button" class="first changePg" name="first" id="firstPg" value="&nbsp;&Iota;&nbsp;&lt;&nbsp;" title="Click here to show first page records">&laquo;</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ $pg_url_param . ($pg_current - 1) }}" type="button" class="previous changePg" name="prev" id="previousPg" value="&nbsp;&lt;&lt;&nbsp;" title="Click here to show previous page records">&lsaquo;</a></li>
        @endif

            <li><input class="" type="text" name="paginationPgNo" id="paginationPgNo" readonly="readonly" value="{{ $pg_current }} of {{ $pg_last }}" /></li>

        @if ($pg_current >= $pg_last)
            <li><a type="button" class="next changePg disabled" name="next" id="nextPg" value="&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&nbsp;" title="Click here to show next page records">&rsaquo;</a></li>
            <li><a type="button" class="last changePg disabled" name="last" id="lastPg" value="&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&Iota;&nbsp;" title="Click here to show last page records">&raquo;</a></li> 
        @else
            <li><a href="{{ $pg_url_param . ($pg_current + 1) }}" type="button" class="next changePg" name="next" id="nextPg" value="&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&nbsp;" title="Click here to show next page records">&rsaquo;</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ $pg_url_param . $pg_last }}" type="button" class="last changePg" name="last" id="lastPg" value="&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&Iota;&nbsp;" title="Click here to show last page records">&raquo;</a></li>
        @endif
        </ul>
    </div>
```

my view blade which is already contain cu index

```
 <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                        <label for="sm" class="control-label">{{ __('messages.module.customer') }}</label>
                        <select class="input-sm form-control" name="cu" id="cu" >
                            @if(request()->session()->get('loginrole') == 'L04')
                            @if(!empty($content->custUserList))
                            @foreach($content->custUserList as $custuser)


                            @if(isset($custuser->irel__h_d_customer_master))
                            @if($custuser->rcu_customer_id ==   $custuser->irel__h_d_customer_master->cu_customer_ID)
                            <option value="{{  $custuser->irel__h_d_customer_master->cu_customer_ID }}">{{  $custuser->irel__h_d_customer_master->cu_customer_Shortname}} - {{  $custuser->irel__h_d_customer_master->cu_customer_Name }}</option>
                            @endif
                            @endif


                            @endforeach
                            @endif
                            @else
                            <option value="">{{ __('messages.select') }}</option>
                            @if(!empty($content->custUserList))
                            @foreach($content->custUserList as $custuser)


                            @if(isset($custuser->irel__h_d_customer_master))
                            @if($custuser->rcu_customer_id ==   $custuser->irel__h_d_customer_master->cu_customer_ID)
                            <option value="{{  $custuser->irel__h_d_customer_master->cu_customer_ID }}">{{  $custuser->irel__h_d_customer_master->cu_customer_Shortname}} - {{  $custuser->irel__h_d_customer_master->cu_customer_Name }}</option>
                            @endif
                            @endif


                            @endforeach
                            @endif
                            @endif
                        </select> 
                    </div>
```

my Controller

```
public function searchIncident(Request $request){



 if(isset($_GET["page"])) {
            $g_page = "?page=" . filter_var($_GET["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        } else {
            $g_page = null;
        }

       // dd($g_page);


        $cust = filter_var($_GET["cu"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $customer = explode(' ',$cust);
        $branch = filter_var($_GET["br"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $category = filter_var($_GET["ct"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $pciisms = ['PCI','ISMS']  ;
        //dd($pciisms);
        $state = filter_var($_GET["stt"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $severity = filter_var($_GET["sv"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $logno = filter_var($_GET["cm"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $status = filter_var($_GET["st"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $group = filter_var($_GET["gr"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $createdby = filter_var($_GET["crtedBy"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $vendor = filter_var($_GET["ven"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $vendorrptno = filter_var($_GET["rptno"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $datefrom = filter_var($_GET["dtFrom"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $dateto = filter_var($_GET["dtTo"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $clsddatefrom = filter_var($_GET["dtClosedFrom"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $clsddateto = filter_var($_GET["dtClosedTo"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $probtype = filter_var($_GET["JpnProbType"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $caller = filter_var($_GET["callerName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $person = filter_var($_GET["personName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $custrptno = filter_var($_GET["cuRpt"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $assetsn = filter_var($_GET["assetSN"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $supplier = filter_var($_GET["sup"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $receivedby = filter_var($_GET["rcvdBy"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $closedby = filter_var($_GET["clsdBy"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);




        $options = [
            'headers' => [  
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
            ],
            'json' => [
                'customer' => $customer,
                'branch' => $branch,
                'category' => $category,
                'pciisms' => $pciisms,
                'state' => $state,
                'severity' => $severity,
                'logno' => $logno,
                'status' => $status,
                'group' => $group,
                'createdby' => $createdby,
                'vendor' => $vendor,
                'vendorrptno' => $vendorrptno,
                'datefrom' => $datefrom,
                'dateto' => $dateto,
                'clsddatefrom' => $clsddatefrom,
                'clsddateto' => $clsddateto,
                'probtype' => $probtype,
                'caller' => $caller,
                'person' => $person,
                'custrptno' => $custrptno,
                'assetsn' => $assetsn,
                'supplier' => $supplier,
                'receivedby' => $receivedby,
                'closedby' => $closedby,

            ],
        ];



        $response =  $this->client->post('searchIncident'.$g_page, $options)->getBody();
        $content = json_decode($response->getContents());
        $paginationRecord = $content->data->incidentList ;



        return view('incident.HDCaseMasterList', compact('paginationRecord'));


}
```

All data was set 15 per page . The data was pull from backend project. I expect all the data was shown on the next page. Hope its help and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

Your undefined index is occurring here:

```
$cust = filter_var($_GET["cu"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

The quickest/easiest solution here (for the specific problem being asked about here, which is the problem of the undefined index error), would be to either (1) actually define it beforehand (not really *best* practise in this particular case, given we're talking about an index of $_GET; the reasons for my saying this being a little outside the scope of the question, so moving on..), or (2) just guard/check for the existence of it beforehand (the better of these two mentioned solutions).

Example of solution 1:

```
if (!isset($_GET["cu"])) {
    $_GET["cu"] = '';
}
$cust = filter_var($_GET["cu"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Example of solution 2 (using fully-formed if/else; most verbose; may be more/less preferred, depending on code-style preferences):

```
if (isset($_GET["cu"])) {
    $cust = filter_var($_GET["cu"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
} else {
    $cust = "";
}
```

Example of solution 2 (using ternary; less verbose; may be more/less preferred, depending on code-style preferences):

```
$cust = filter_var(isset($_GET["cu"]) ? $_GET["cu"] : "", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Example of solution 2 (using null coalescence; least verbose; may be more/less preferred, depending on code-style preferences; best if targeting PHP versions >= 7 only; won't work if support for PHP < 7 is required for your project):

```
$cust = filter_var($_GET["cu"] ?? "", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

*Note: My reply is specifically addressing only the undefined index error. I haven't tested or audited your code, so whether there are other problems, or other things that need addressing, I wouldn't yet know.*

Comment: thanks sir....but if my $cust value null , it will return nothing on another page , any solution?

Comment: You're welcome. :-)

You mean `null` or `false`? The PHP documentation describes the return value for `filter_var()` as `mixed` (i.e., it should generally return a value of the same type as the variable supplied to it in the first place), or if something goes wrong (i.e., an error occurs), as `false`. As the value of `$cust` is coming from `filter_var()`, it shouldn't (in theory) ever be `null`, unless `null` is supplied to that particular `filter_var()` call in the first place. In the case of `false`, just set a default value to use. :-) *(Edit: I hit enter before by mistake).*